# Android: ListView column sizing to first item

Tags: android, css, listview

I have a ListView inside of a HorizontalScrollView which I'm using as a small panel overlaying a fragment.  It all would work as expected if the longest item were the top item.  When the shortest is, the ListView's width takes on the width of that item and then there's no horizontal scrolling.  The rest of the items are just cropped.

Here is the pertinent portions of the layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/vendorListContainer"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#50FFFFFF"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/vendorList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

I'm using the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 as the item layout.  Should I be using a custom layout with some special options chosen to fix this?  I thought of just padding all the strings, but that's a hack I'd rather avoid.  What am I doing wrong?